# How do I get the file HANDLE from the fopen FILE structure?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-ce, msvcrt, crt

The `fopen` function returns a pointer to a `FILE` structure, which should be considered an opaque value, without dealing with its content or meaning.

On Windows, the C runtime is a wrapper of the Windows API, and the `fopen` function relies on the `CreateFile` function. The `CreateFile` function returns a `HANDLE`, which is used by other Windows API.

Now, I need to use Windows API deep inside of a library that uses `fopen` and `FILE*`. So: is there a way to get the `HANDLE` from the `FILE` structure? As this is compiler specific, I mean on the MSVC runtime library.

I understand that this would be an ugly, non-portable hack, and that could broke if Microsoft changes the internal format of `FILE`... but I'm developing on a closed system (i.e. on a Windows CE embedded system) and refactoring the library would be difficult and time consuming.

Comment: Great question, I dealt with this one myself over 2 years ago.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `_fileno` followed by `_get_osfhandle`. Don't forget to `_close` it when you are done.

EDIT: it's not clear to me that `_get_osfhandle` is supported on WinCE.  However the docs for WinCE `_fileno` say it returns a "file handle" rather than "descriptor". YMMV but this suggests that you can maybe just use `_fileno` return value directly as a handle on WinCE.

EDIT: #2 That theory is supported by [this person's experience](http://www.equi4.com/pub/am/metakit/2002-February/000512.html).

"If you take a look at the header files that I posted to the list on Jan 29
you can see how I handled the file creation/handle problem.  I didn't have
to replace all FILE* items with HANDLEs.  See the following snippet from
fileio.cpp:

```
#ifndef q4_WCE

  FlushFileBuffers((HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(_fileno(_file)));
  HANDLE h = ::CreateFileMapping((HANDLE)
_get_osfhandle(_fileno(_file)),
                        0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, len, 0);
#else

  FlushFileBuffers((HANDLE) _fileno(_file));
  HANDLE h = ::CreateFileMapping((HANDLE) _fileno(_file),
                    0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, len, 0);
#endif //q4_WCE
```

It turns out that _fileno returns a handle.  You just have to cast it."

Comment: Thank you, _fileno was good enough for my Windows CE issue, but your answer seems actually "portable" on all the MS platforms with any version of MSVC.

Answer (score 8):

On Linux, there's the `int fileno(FILE *);` function that returns the file descriptor (the one that was returned by the low-level `open` function) from the `FILE*`.

I don't know if it applies to Windows and returns the HANDLE though?

Comment: Hmm, that's possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee479262.aspx states that "_fileno gets file handle associated with stream". At least on Windows CE it should work.

Comment: It is just a compat function for *nix.  Handles are pointer sized, 8 bytes on Win64.

Answer (score 5):

For C, try this

```c
HANDLE foo = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fileno(fopen("bar.txt", "w")));
```

Comment: Used later, this is telling me the handle is invalid for e.g. stdout.