# How do I retrieve the FILE* of a CreateFile result?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

See title.

How do I achieve the opposite of this question: [How do I get the file HANDLE from the fopen FILE structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989545/how-do-i-get-the-file-handle-from-the-fopen-file-structure)

I create the handle with

```
      HANDLE h = CreateFile(name,
                            GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            OPEN_ALWAYS,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            NULL);
```

and then try to write some data to it using `fputs`.

The call to `fputs` fails on the line

```
_VALIDATE_STREAM_ANSI_RETURN(stream, EINVAL, EOF);
```

where `stream` is the handle I obtained from `CreateFile`.

---

The reason why I'm doing that is that I use an external library that uses `FILE*` handles and I'm not opening a plain file (as until now) but trying to write to a pipe instead. And changing the external library is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way but see `_open_osfhandle()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x(v=vs.71).aspx

```
int fd = _open_osfhandle(h, ...);
```

It returns a file descriptor which you'll have to open using `fdopen` to get a `FILE*`.

```
FILE* fp = _fdopen(fd, ...);
```