# Pass FILE_ATTRIBUTE constants to C runtime functions

Tags: winapi, posix, createfile, win32-process

I am trying to optimize a legacy application written in C which makes uses of regular `stdio.h` resp. `fcntl.h` functions. For special uses, I would like to inject a few extra hints from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants to newly opened file handles.

But those are available only to low-level Win32 APIs. Is there a way to pass the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_... options to the `open()` call somehow? Or is there somewhere a sane wrapper which would open a file handle "win32 way" with custom options and hand it over as integer file descriptor just like `open()` would do it?

Comment: It's not clear if you need to _open_ the file with those attributes or you can set them after the fact.  Seems there may be an API call you can make to get the `HANDLE` to the file descriptor using `_get_osfhanle(fileno(fp))` where `fp` is your `FILE*`.  Something you can try, at least.

Comment: There is no way to make `open` act like `CreateFile`. `open` has requirements set by POSIX that don't align to Win32. Furthermore it's not even part of the C standard but a method that MSVC supports out of convenience. C would have you use `FILE*`. If you must do what you're asking you can use [`_open_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?source=recommendations&view=msvc-170) after using `CreateFile`. But be aware you still need to close the OS handle with `CloseHandle` and manage all the cleanup quirks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359188/how-do-i-retrieve-the-file-of-a-createfile-result

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions that convert between Win32 file handles and file descriptors:

- [`intptr_t _get_osfhandle(int fd);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-osfhandle?view=msvc-170) will get you a `HANDLE`from a given `fd`
- [`int _open_osfhandle(intptr_t osfhandle, int flags);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle?view=msvc-170) will get you an `fd` from a `HANDLE`

Note that for both:

> The _open_osfhandle call transfers ownership of the Win32 file handle
> to the file descriptor. To close a file opened by using
> _open_osfhandle, call _close

> To close a file whose operating system (OS) file handle is obtained by
> _get_osfhandle, call _close on the file descriptor fd. Never call CloseHandle on the return value of this function. ...

If you want to set the attributes at *creation* time, you would need to use `CreateFile` and then convert to a fd, because afaics there is no API to *set* attributes on a given `HANDLE`, there's only [`SetFileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesw) which operates on a name.

If you just wanna query the attributes, you can use [`GetFileInformationByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle).