# How do I flush a stdlib output file on win32?

Tags: c++, windows, flush, std

I have a C++ program that is writing to a file on Windows 7.  When I call `f.flush()` the NTFS file does not get bigger. Is there any way to force the file to get flushed?

Comment: Are you sure there is pending output? Also, fsync (or [`_commit`]()) is your friend (http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers-win32/2003-11/msg00082.php)

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm positive there is output. It's not pending --- it's been sent. But NTFS buffers.

Comment: It is a heavy CRT implementation detail.  For the MSVC CRT it is done by passing 'c' (= commit) to the fopen() *mode* argument.  Look through the source of the one you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look here:
[How do I get the file HANDLE from the fopen FILE structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989545/how-do-i-get-the-file-handle-from-the-fopen-file-structure) 
the code looks like this:

```
 FlushFileBuffers((HANDLE) _fileno(_file));
```

do not forget call fflush(file), before call FlusFileBuffers.

For std::fstream and gnu stl, I checked it on my linux box, have no windows at home,
but should work with mingw, may be need some modifications:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc == 2);
    std::ifstream f(argv[1]);
    assert(!!f);
/*
    //cin, cout etc
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> *stdio_buf = dynamic_cast<__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> *>(f.rdbuf());
    if (stdio_buf != 0) {
        printf("your fd is %d\n", stdio_buf->fd());
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
*/
    std::basic_filebuf<char> *file_buf = dynamic_cast<std::basic_filebuf<char> *>(f.rdbuf());
    if (file_buf != 0) {
        struct to_get_protected_member : public std::basic_filebuf<char> {
            int fd() { return _M_file.fd(); }
        };
        printf("your fd is %d\n", static_cast<to_get_protected_member *>(file_buf)->fd());
    }
    printf("what is going on?\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: But that is a C `FILE*` object, not a C++ `iostream` object.

Comment: This is more hard, in library that come with VS10, you can construct std::fstream object from FILE, on some other libraries, I saw std::fstream::fd method, to file descriptor from std::fstream. What compiler do you use?

Comment: I'm using mingw as a cross-compiler from Fedora Core. So I'm using GNU STL.

Comment: I did not find a `f.fd()` method.

Comment: Update my answer, to include code that I was used some time before to get file handle.

Comment: @user1034749 This is much better than my `#define protected public` trick!!

Comment: Btw `dynamic_cast` wasn't necessary with g++ 4.6.3 / Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

`flush` only flushes the internal buffers kept by the standard library code.

To flush the OS's buffers, you'd need/want to call `FlushFileBuffers` (*after* calling `f.flush()`).

Comment: That's great. However, `FlushFileBuffers` requires the hFile handle. How do I get that?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: fsync() doesn't do the trick; I need to call FlushFileBuffers; I just need to find the handle.