# Using fsync() for saving binary files in C or C++

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-io, binaryfiles

My computer recently got shut down abruptly. When I powered it back on, I found out that some of the binary files I had written when the computer was running last time got corrupted. I investigated this, found that this is because data written using `fwrite` is not guaranteed to be written to disk immediately. I was told that in order to save my data without the risk of losing it in case of another abrupt power outage, I should make use of `fsync` function. But it looks like it is [Unix/Linux only facility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) located in `unistd.h`. I am on Windows, how do I do the equivalent of `fsync` on Windows?

I want to protect data written using a simple program as follows -

```
void WriteBinFile(float var1, float var2, float var3)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, "filename.dat", "wb");
    fwrite((void*)&var1, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
    fwrite((void*)&var2, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
    fwrite((void*)&var3, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
    // fsync(fp) ??? No such function exists on Windows. Here I want a facility to write data to disk in non-volatile manner.
    fclose(fp);
}
```

P.S. Why I don't have a UPS is a long and an uninteresting story.Also, I am on Windows 8.1 and using Visual Studio 2013. Also, the files that were affected due to the abrupt power outage contained `0`s. Some of them were full of `0`s and some of them were only partially full of `0`s. I did not write `0`s to the file, so this was definitely a consequence of the power outage

Comment: If your files got corrupted, you should use a proper filesystem. Normally you only should have lost the last data written, but no corruption. Eitehr way, 'fsync' will slow down operations massively. In general, a UPS is definitively a better invest.

Comment: @набиячлевэлиь: Nonsense, that is something completely different.

Comment: Pick a language. C is not C++!

Comment: @Olaf The files contained `0`s, which is not what I wrote to them. So, I guess I did lose the data, as opposed it getting corrupted. I  used thw word corrupted because I conflated the two when I wrote the question

Comment: @Olaf I tagged both languages because I am open to suggestions for C++ only code which will fix the problem.

Comment: Still pick a language. As you should do it differently in C++, I presume it is C. Therefore: Do not cast to/from `void *`.

Comment: @Olaf the code is originally C++. Picked a language

Comment: If you use CreateFIle etc., there are flags to omit every buffer (but it gets inconvenient, because you always need to write full HDD blocks etc.etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stop reading after the first paragraph, there are **three** steps following.

1. Call `fflush(fp)`. This will flush all of the data out of the C stdio buffers and into the operating system buffers.
2. Use [How do I get the file HANDLE from the fopen FILE structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989545/how-do-i-get-the-file-handle-from-the-fopen-file-structure/3989842#3989842)
3. Then call `FlushFileBuffers` on the HANDLE. This will flush all of the data out of the Windows OS buffers and onto the disk.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if `fflush(fp)` also works for this?

Comment: @FirstJens: I forget to mention fflush at first until I saw it in Joshua's answer. It is needed to get the data out of the buffer built into C's stdio functions. After that you need FlushFileBuffers to get the data out of the operating system buffers.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading through the code now. It is quite dense.

Comment: Wow, two downvotes without a single explanatory comment.

Comment: `fflush()` does not correspond to `fsync()`. The former is a C library function that flushes buffers out of the application into the kernel: the latter is a system call that flushes buffers out of the kernel onto the disk. On systems that have them both you would need to use them both to accomplish the OP's objective. The Windows equivalent to `fsync()` is `FlushFileBuffer()`.

Comment: @EJP: It seems your comment just restated my answer?

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is [`FlushFileBuffers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx). In your case, `FlushFileBuffers(fileno(fd))`.

Another useful idiom in Windows is given by `close(dup(fd))`, or in your case `close(dup(fileno(fp)))`. This flushes the directory entry, so that the file size is correct for a growing file. Otherwise the directory is only updated when the file is closed.

Answer (score -4):

I could be wrong, but I believe that `fflush(fp);` should do the trick.

Comment: While not wrong, this only affects the C runtime buffering. Windows may have another level (it does have it).