# fseek internally calls _invalid_parameter_noinfo when mixing C and C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, dllexport

I have the following (minimal example) library:

```c
#include "filesizelib.h"

long get_size_example(FILE* file)
{
    printf("Called.\n");
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    printf("SEEK_END finished.\n");
    long file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    printf("SEEK_SET finished.\n");
    return file_size;
}
```

(NOTE: `get_size_example` assumes the given file was already opened via `fopen` with `rb` mode.)

filesizelib.h is as follows:

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) long get_size_example(FILE* file);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And here's how I compile the library (with debug info):

```
cl /LD /Zi filesizelib.cpp
```

It compiles successfully. Now we need a C test program (main.c):

```c
#include "lib/filesizelib.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("MyBinaryFile.bin", "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the binary file in rb mode!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    long file_size = get_size_example(file);
    printf("File size: %ld\n", file_size);
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Compilation:

```
cl main.c /Zi /link filesizelib.lib /LIBPATH:lib
```

This also compiles successfully, and generates **main.exe**.

Running main.exe, however, yields a crash on the library's (filesizelib) code. Namely here...

```c
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
```

How can I ensure that the call to `fseek` does not crash? Windows seems to be invoking `_invalid_parameter_noinfo` as a result of this call. Is this due to mixing C code with a C++-based library?

Additional context: I'm working on a project whose codebase (for the most part) is in C++, yet the client requires that the SDK provide an API in C.

Do note that, if all the code is scoped to a single C program, it seems to work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("MyBinaryFile.bin", "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the binary file in rb mode!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    long file_size = 0L;
    printf("Called.\n");
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    printf("SEEK_END finished.\n");
    file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    printf("SEEK_SET finished.\n");
    printf("File size: %ld\n", file_size);
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Output:

```
Called.
SEEK_END finished.
SEEK_SET finished.
File size: 1741
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I pass FILE object across DLLs boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46078523/11683)

Comment: @GSerg Yes, both of those answer my question. My apologies; I was unaware that passing the FILE object across DLL boundaries does not necessarily work/yield the result I was expecting.