# FILE vs HANDLE - what is the difference between these two things

Tags: c, windows, file

So, I'm running on Windows and need to figure out the size of a file.

SO mentions `GetFileSize` in many places, which takes a `HANDLE`. I'm used to just working with `FILE`s returned from `fopen` and such.

1. What is the difference between `FILE` and the Windows `HANDLE`? When should each be used?
2. For example, can I pass a plain `FILE` obtained from `fopen` to `GetFileSize`? Or do I need to use the Windows `CreateFile` (?) function to get a `HANDLE` and then pass it in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423628/whats-the-difference-between-a-file-descriptor-and-file-pointer

Comment: also GetFileSize is a windows only function, not standard c

Comment: worth mentioning that the `stdio.h` closest equivalent (which will let you pass a `FILE*`) is `fseek(SEEK_END)` followed by `ftell()`.  And the equivalent on other OSes (which is in the POSIX standard but not the C standard, and does not use `FILE*`) is `fstat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FILE` is a type of the standard C library, used exclusively for file handling with the stdio.h functions. It cannot be used for anything else. The C standard lib has the advantage of being portable.

`HANDLE` is a similar but wider concept used by the Windows API, used for everything where they want an abstraction layer on top of raw pointers. It is used for files, ports, threads, mutex, events, pipes and so on. Generally: any Windows resource that you can `WaitForSingleObject` on - the `WaitFor...` functions being Window's way of letting a thread effectively sleep without using up CPU resources. See [What is a Windows Handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902967/what-is-a-windows-handle). It only works for Windows API specific-functions like `CreateFile`.

Both of these are "opaque types" that the application programmer doesn't know or care about how they are implemented internally.

In practice, the standard C library port for Windows is just an abstraction layer on top of the Windows API. So `FILE* fp = fopen("", "w");` will very likely boil down to a `CreateFile` call internally. So for all we know, `FILE` could contain a `HANDLE` internally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989545/how-do-i-get-the-file-handle-from-the-fopen-file-structure

Comment: `fopen` calls `_open`. The latter returns a C file descriptor. This in turn wraps a Windows File handle, which comes from an internal `CreateFileW` call. A File handle refers to a kernel File object. Handles for kernel objects also include the access granted to the object at the time the handle was opened, along with flags that determine whether the handle can be closed via `CloseHandle` and whether it can be inherited by a child process.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetFileSize()` function with `HANDLE` are part of the Windows API which means that it is only usable with a Windows program.

The `fopen()` and `FILE` are part of the C Runtime library that comes with any standard C compiler which means that using those should be operating system independent.

You can not pass a `FILE` to the `GetFileSize()` function because a `HANDLE` and a `FILE` are two different things.